# Auto show div after few seconds javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I just want a simple div that contains some images to show after a certain amount of seconds or minutes. im using a basic bootstrap site.

Comment: i just can seem to figure it out :(.. Im using a bootstrap theme and its just not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/L9fe0py3/6/

I used jQuery

HTML:

```
<div id="thisDiv" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://bxslider.com/images/home_slides/hillside.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function(){
$('#thisDiv').fadeIn();
}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try the below code Hope It Helps

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#divname').delay(1000).fadeIn();
   });
  </script>
```

and the css

```
 #divname
  {
  background-image: url("mm.jpg");
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  display:none;

   }
```